# Proper VBA code to close workbook without saving

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Whenever the code is executed while multiple workbooks are open, office stops working with a message

> Microsoft Office Excel has stopped working
>
> Windows can try to recover your information and restart the program.

What's wrong with the code? I'm using MS Office 2007 on Windows7

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    close_without_saving
End Sub

Sub close_without_saving()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True

    If Application.Workbooks.Count < 2 Then
        Application.Quit
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This code would not compile. You have kept one sub within another sub.It should give you ~Compile error~ ~Invalid outside procedure~. If you have two subs correct practice is to call one sub from the another.

Comment: Corrected the code.. I'm calling the close_without_saving sub in Workbook_BeforeClose

Comment: What is the purpose of this routine? Do you want to close the workbook without incorporating changes. Then you can use code like this in workbook module ~Sub Auto_Close()
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub~

Comment: I want to close this workbook with the close X button without saving changes while not affecting other opened worksheets.

Comment: You can also use this for closing workbook without saving changes.     ~Sub CloseBook2()
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub~ This routine can be attached to Close X Button. Workbook never closes partially, it will always close with all sheets contained in this workbook.

Comment: Wouldn't the `DisplayAlerts = False` prevent a popup when calling `Thisworkbook.Close()` without arguments? Could this be the reason Excel is crashing?

Comment: @Michael Z Yes this DisplayAlerts = False and subsequently True can be incorporated in the routine. That should not create a problem, ~Sub CloseBook()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub~

Comment: The proper way is as @skkakkar suggested by passing the argument into `Close()`

Comment: @skkakkar could you make that answer because it is the proper answer to this very common question?

Comment: @skkakkar sub CloseBook2() solves the problem. Thanks. But I still don't understand what's wrong with the code I'm using.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but maybe the DisplayAlerts = False caused an Excel issue when you tried to close a workbook while others were still open. That's why you should skip the DisplayAlerts - False and do it the proper way.

Comment: If you changed your code to close the workbook instead of quitting the app when it's the only workbook would it crash Excel or would it leave you with an empty Excel instance? If it does not crash then it might point back to what I just said about blocking the alert when more than 1 book is open.

Comment: Regarding your code I shall look into and try to analyse in detail what is at fault for your and my learning.

Comment: @skkakkar I'm glad you are because I am curious now. The code looks like it should work fine and it might even be an isolated issue. Repairing/Re-installing Excel might correct the issue.

Comment: @ZuriPow This code worked as expected with Excel 2016 on WIndows 10. I don't have Windows 7 or Excel 2007. You should test your code on other machines too.

Comment: Your corrected program works fine on my Excel 2016

Comment: Maybe then its just in my machine. I will repair install and check again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If  you want to close the workbook without incorporating changes. Then you can use code like this in workbook module ~

```
Sub Auto_Close() 
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True 
End Sub
```

You can also use this for closing workbook without saving changes.

```
Sub CloseBook2() 
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False 
End Sub
```

This routine can be attached to Close X Button. Workbook never closes partially, it will always close with all sheets contained in this workbook. DisplayAlerts = False and subsequently True can be incorporated in the routine. That should not create a problem like

```
Sub CloseBook() 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
    ActiveWorkbook.Close 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
End Sub
```

Comment: @MichaelZ ZuriPow program works fine on my Excel 2016

Comment: Yep mine too. It seems like the issue is specific to the machine and it should be tested on other Windows 7 machines running excel 2007.