What is necessary to quit Powerpoint through VBA code from Access?
I suspect I'm missing something very basic here, but manipulating Powerpoint from within Access is apparently so rare that I'm forging blind.
Here's the situation: I need to be able to select a Powerpoint file, export the first slide as a JPG, and then save a copy into an archive folder. All of that has been achieved. The problem is getting Powerpoint to then go away afterwards.
Close and Quit both do nothing. Trying to set the application's visibility to false to enable it to complete the process in the background also does nothing.
Here's the code as it currently stands.
Sub ExportPresentation(strPath As String)
        
    Dim objPPT As Object
       
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set objPPT = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    End If
    
    With objPPT
        .Presentations.Open strPath
        .Application.Visible = False
        .ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Export ArchiveFolderLocation & "Test" & ".jpg", "JPG"
    
        .ActivePresentation.SaveCopyAs2 ArchiveFolderLocation & "Test"
        .Presentation.Close
        .Application.Quit
    End With

End Sub


I've tried without the .Application as well, on the guess that that was inherent in the objPPT, but still nothing. Theoretically I could do something to call upon a macro within the imported file, but that's not logistically viable to implement.
What am I missing?

Sidenote:  After using Resume Next set back immediately to Goto 0. Not to loose an error.

Because application is not visible (.Application.Visible = False), you should make sure not question is asked when closing it. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475304/proper-vba-code-to-close-workbook-without-saving which has an example on closing Excel (but PowerPoint should make not much difference)

According to the Microsoft documentation, Presentation.Close should skip any save-related queries, and I'm not sure what else would arise from this?
Additionally, the visibility switch doesn't seem to be doing anything. I commented it out just to be sure, no visible (hah) effect.

Try .ActivePresentation.Close and .Quit is working fine for me (after closing the presentation)

If I turn error handling back on I get a message on the .Application.Visible = False saying the method does not exist. Remove the .Application piece "Invalid Request. Hiding the Application window is not allowed" - which makes sense to me. You could try minimising it instead


You may need to Set objPPT = Nothing and 2) if you have file explorer set to show a preview and you have a PowerPoint file selected, there'll be a hidden instance of PowerPoint invoked to create the preview. If you see two instances while your code is running and one after, this might be the reason.


In contrast to Access, the PowerPoint Application object doesn't have an Application member that references itself.
objPPT is a Powerpoint Application object, meaning .Application.Visible = False references the application member of the application object. That is not valid code for PowerPoint.
Adjust accordingly:
Sub ExportPresentation(strPath As String)
        
    Dim objPPT As Object
       
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set objPPT = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0 'As Black cat mentioned, would've made this error easy to spot
    With objPPT
        .Presentations.Open strPath
        .Visible = False
        .ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Export ArchiveFolderLocation & "Test" & ".jpg", "JPG"
    
        .ActivePresentation.SaveCopyAs2 ArchiveFolderLocation & "Test"
        .ActivePresentation.Close 'As pointed out by Chill60, extra error
        .Quit
    End With

End Sub

In Access you can do something like Application.Application.Application.Quit. That's not the case in PowerPoint
